# Unity C# How do I make a random number that doesn't repeat?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I am trying to make code that gives me a random variable from a list of strings, but I do not want it to give me a variable I already got.

Here some code for u my dude ↓↓↓

```
    public Text[] elements;
    public string[] variables;

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            elements[i].text = variables[Random.Range(0, variables.Length)];           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the numbers in a list. Random one number between 0 and size of list. Then remove that number from the list

Comment: The way to go is actually simply shuffle the list, then go through them one by one, see duplicate links

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list and remove an item once you've used it

```
public List<string> variables = new List<string>();
public Text[] elements;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = variables[Random.Range(0, variables.Count - 1)];
        elements[i].text = s;
        variables.Remove(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without creating new data structure, you can do:

```
public Text[] elements;
public string[] variables;

void Start()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {
        string randomVariable;

        do {
           randomVariable = variables[Random.Range(0, variables.Length)];
        } while (Arrays.asList(elements).contains(randomString));

        elements[i].text = randomVariable;           
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one way but probably the worst way to go though ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by creating list of possible numbers, and remove the numbers once you find from the list-

```
public Text[] elements;
public string[] variables;

void Start()
{
    Random rndom = new Random();
    List<int> possible = Enumerable.Range(0, variables.Length).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
    {  
        int index = rndom.Next(0, possible.Count);
        elements[i].text = variables[possible[index]];
        Console.WriteLine(possible[index]);
        possible.RemoveAt(index);               
     }
}
```

Output

```
2
1
0
3
```